# How to compare slice of struct

Tags: arrays, go, struct, slice

```golang
type RecordProxy struct {
    Amt   int    `csv:"Amt"`
    Descr string `csv:"Descr"`
    Date  string `csv:"Date"`
    ID    string `csv:"ID"`
}

type RecordSource struct {
    Date        string `csv:"Date"`
    ID          string `csv:"ID"`
    Amount      int    `csv:"Amount"`
    Description string `csv:"Description"`
}
```

i have a slice of struct `[]RecordProxy` and `[]RecordSource`
i want to check if this 2 slice of struct is equal.

do you have any idea?

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work?

Comment: The two slices or their structs will *never* be equal as far as the equality operator `==` is concerned because the struct types are different, not only in name but also in structure. If, in the context of your program, a source can be equal to a proxy, then you'll have to implement your own custom way of comparing the two for equality.

Answer (score 2):

As @mkopriva comments "you have to implement your own custom way of comparing", i.e. tell what rules to according to the two slices could be considered equal.

Only an example:

```golang
func CompareRecords(a []RecordProxy, b []RecordSource) bool {
    lengthA, lengthB := len(a), len(b)
    if lengthA != lengthB {
        return false
    }

    for i := range a {
        // define your own unequal rules:
        if a[i].Amt != b[i].Amount ||
            // other rules for fields of structs...
            a[i].Date != b[i].Date {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the better way to compare slice of structs ( a, b) is using reflect if

```
if len(a) != len(b) {
   return false
}

flag := true
for i:=0; len(a); i++{
    if reflect.DeepEqual(a[i], b[i]) {
      falg = true
   } else {
      flag = flase
   }
}
//verify flag
if flag == false{
  return false
} else {
 return true
}
```